# json merge in multidimensional array decode not working

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, jsondecoder

My json looks like this

```
 [ 
   { 
      "name":"test.xlsx",
      "type":"application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
      "tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpEFF8.tmp",
      "error":0,
      "size":3278935
   },
   { 
      "name":"test2.pptx",
      "type":"application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
      "tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpF018.tmp",
      "error":0,
      "size":41167
   }
],
[ 
   { 
      "name":"images.jpg",
      "type":"image\/jpeg",
      "tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php8C1.tmp",
      "error":0,
      "size":9077
   }
]
```

I want to set as one array like this [0] [1] [2]

Expected array

```
  array (
  [0] => array (
      ['name'] => 'test.xlsx',
      ['type'] => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      ['tmp_name'] => 'D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php1926.tmp',
      ['error'] => 0,
      ['size'] => 3278935
      )
  [1] => array (
      ['name'] => 'test2.pptx',
      ['type'] => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
      ['tmp_name'] => 'D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php1956.tmp',
      ['error'] => 0,
      ['size'] => 41167
      ) 
   [2] => array (
      ['name'] => 'images.jpg',
      ['type'] => 'image/jpeg',
      ['tmp_name'] => 'D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php5A68.tmp',
      ['error'] => 0,
      ['size'] => 9077
      )
  )
)
```

PHP I tried like this

```
    $examples ='{[ 
   { 
      "name":"test.xlsx",
      "type":"application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
      "tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpEFF8.tmp",
      "error":0,
      "size":3278935
   },
   { 
      "name":"test2.pptx",
      "type":"application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
      "tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpF018.tmp",
      "error":0,
      "size":41167
   }
],
[ 
   { 
      "name":"images.jpg",
      "type":"image\/jpeg",
      "tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php8C1.tmp",
      "error":0,
      "size":9077
   }
]}';
$examples = json_decode($examples);
print_r($examples);
```

Comment: I hope your json is valid, so do this:- https://3v4l.org/YLZZr

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie thanks it was correct